# How do I determine the authorization scheme of an Oracle APEX user?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle APEX program where I need to determine if the current user fits within a given authorization scheme at run time. There are multiple schemes in the application and on a certain page, three have access to see it. Two of them have full read-write access to the fields displayed, while users from the other one have read-only privileges to the page.

How can I determine the user's scheme?

I am using Application Express 4.2.3.00.08.

Once I do that, I plan to do something like this in the page footer:

```
<script>
if ( '&NAME_OF_SCHEMA.'  == 'DLR_READ_ONLY') {
    $('input[type="text"]').attr('readonly','readonly');
}
</script>
```

Comment: apex version? Security schema = authorisation scheme?

Comment: @Tom, edited answers into the body.

Comment: There's not really any such thing as **"the"** authorization scheme of an Apex user - any number of authorization schemes may very well evaluate to "true" for any user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest route is to check the scheme in the read-only attribute of the page instead of relying on javascript. This will render all elements in read-only on your page, as if you'd set the region or item level read-only attribute.

[image: Edit page definition]
[image: PLSQL expression read only condition]

[apex_util.public_check_authorization documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_util.htm#AEAPI161)